# Reverse the order of an integer in C

Tags: c

I am currently learning C as part of a course and I have a task to reverse the order of a number without using any arithmetic (wording of the task). 
I currently have this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
   int n, reverse = 0; 

   printf("Enter a number to reverse\n"); 
   scanf("%d", &n); 

   while (n != 0) { 
       reverse = reverse * 10; 
       reverse = reverse + n_10; 
       n       = n / 10; 
   } 

   printf("Reverse of entered number is = %d\n", reverse); 

   return 0; 
}
```

But this solution uses arithmetic. How can I alter this to complete the task?

From the exercise sheet, "though    even    at  three
digits  the naïve   approach    quickly grows   unmanageable    with    arithmetic  (try    it!).
Your    goal:   Design  3-digit solution without using any arithmetic.(Hint:    use scanf.)"

The wording of the question was confusing but to be clear the question is: 
How do you reverse the order of a number, e.g. 123456789 to 987654321, without without using math. So the solution is to scanf to read the number and swap the numbers in a loop as the answer below.

Comment: I assume by `n_10`, you mean `n % 10`.

Comment: "without using any arithmetic" is a strange constraint .. what about the instruction pointer increment?

Comment: Not using arithmetic for the task implies not handling the input values as numbers.

Comment: "...reverse the order of 3 numbers..."? Where exactly does 3 come into play?

Comment: You cannot do this without using arithmetic. The programm counter in your CPU is very likely incremented or an offset is added for a branch. Both are arithmetic operators. So please clarify your question.

Comment: lol, ' without using any arithmetic. (Hint: use scanf.)' - I suspect that scanf() uses arithmetic, (apart from the obvious arithmetic operations that are required for the binary instruction codes, addressing etc. to be executed at machine code level).

Comment: The CPU program counter and the internals of `scanf` would _maybe_ be relevant if the topic was assembly or machine code, but they are clearly beyond the scope of the C language.

Comment: @NisseEngström: Then the solution is simple: Use Assembler to implement the reversal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just read it in as a string.

```
int main()
{
    char str[80];
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);
    strrev(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
void strrev(char *str)
{
    char *end, tmp;

    end = str + strlen(str) - 1;

    for (; end > str; --end, ++str) {
        tmp = *end;
        *end = *str;
        *str = tmp;
    }
}
```

I don't know if you consider pointer arithmetic to be "arithmetic"

Answer (score 0):

Read as series of short strings that can hold 1 digit and then print in the reserve order.

```
char buf[10][2] = { 0 };
scanf("%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]%1[0-9]", 
    &buf[0], &buf[1], &buf[2], &buf[3], &buf[4], 
    &buf[5], &buf[6], &buf[7], &buf[8], &buf[9]);

printf("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", 
    buf[9], buf[8], buf[7], buf[6], buf[5], 
    buf[4], buf[3], buf[2], buf[1], buf[0]);
```

Obviously limited to max 10 digits.

---

A recusive approach, inpsired by [@Nisse Engström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478852/nisse-engstr%c3%b6m). Works for any reasonable length input.

```
void pr(void) {
  char digit[2];
  if (scanf("%1[0-9]",digit)) {
    pr();
    printf("%s",digit);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  pr();
  return 0;
}
```

Input

```
012345678901234567890123456789
```

Output

```
987654321098765432109876543210
```

Of course `if (scanf("%1[0-9]",digit)) {` should be `if (scanf("%1[0-9]",digit) == 1) {` to cope with `EOF` but that then may be "arithmetic".

Comment: A much better solution would be to read one character at a time from `stdin` in a recursive function, and output them on your way out.

Comment: @Nisse Engström   Agreed, yet it is unclear how much math is allowed in "without using any arithmetic". A recursive solution is bound to have some stopping `if()` condition which may be considered "arithmetic".  So I tried one that has no arithmetic at run-time.  No tests, adds,compares, etc.  Just the assumption of a max 10 digit input and not reading error.

Comment: One could argue that array indexing is equivalent to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Nisse Engström No indexing calculation _needs_ to occur at run-time as all values are constant.  Still it comes down to the "not-so-detailed" requirement of  "without using any arithmetic",

Comment: What is "`%1[0-9]`" supposed to do? (Read it **carefully**!)

Comment: @Olaf The intent of `"%1[0-9]"` was to read up to 1 `char` that is a digit (`'0'` to `'9'`) into an array 2 of  char as a string.  Do you see it differently?  Would you prefer the more portable `"%1[0123456789]"`?

Comment: @chux: Point taken! I don't use `scanf`, etc. often in embedded systems, so I'm not very familar with the "extended features". The range is fine for me, I knew regexpr, just thought there still has to be an `s` or `c` type specifier. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf()`:

```
int
scanf        (){
int
stdin          =
getchar      ();
return
stdin       <0||
stdin         ==
           '\n'?
stdin         :(
scanf        (),
putchar        (
stdin        )),
          '\n';}
int
main         (){
putchar        (
scanf         ()
             );}
```

Answer (score -3):

Read integer, use sprintf() function to convert it into string and then use the library function strrev() to reverse the string.